# Web to database middleware

Tags: html, database, asp-classic

what back end processing takes place when the browser sends a request to the web server for a ***non-static*** page requiring a connection to the database?

I know how it occurs for static web pages, is it the same for non static pages and does the ASP engine have a part to play for the processing of these non static pages?

I'm pretty familiar with databases, but now i'm trying to learn more about databases and how they interact with the internet.

Comment: For a question like this, just google Classic ASP, or even try Wikipedia, and you should find an explanation of what actually goes on on the server.  The "ASP Engine" clearly has a part to play, by definition